# How to view JSON payloads for Email sends?

Tags: json, email, hyperlink, sendgrid

My company is having trouble with account activation emails not sending out the proper activation link within the email so users can complete the account creation process.

We run our email sends through SendGrid and they instructed me to send them my JSON payload for email sends so they can see what the issue is causing this disconnect.

I have never had to work with JSON or pull this type of data and embarrassingly do not know where to start. How would I go about viewing this data?

Comment: How have you implemented sending emails through SendGrid? Did your company write this application, or is it a third party app that is doing the sending for you?

Comment: @philnash we authenticated our domain through SendGrid and added the necessary MX records on our server but a plugin called WP Mail SMTP is handling the delivery of emails on our wordpress site

Comment: OK, so the JSON payload is created and sent to SendGrid by the plugin. I've had a look through the documentation, but I don't know a lot about how the WP Mail SMTP plugin works, or how you interact with it. Perhaps turning on [debug mode](https://wpmailsmtp.com/docs/how-to-debug-email-sending-issues-in-wp-mail-smtp/) and capturing an account activation email might give us some insight?